# PHP/Java Eclipse

Tags: java, php, eclipse, applet

I've created a Java project in Eclipse  that holds applet with Java perspective and another PHP project with PHP perspective that holds file that has javascript to communicate with the java applet. 
Unfortunately I don't know how to setup the Java files into the PHP project  so that the applet works from my localhost.

I had the applet somewhat working when I put the PHP files into Java project and ran it like that but I need it other way so that I can run from my PHP project.Anything is great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep your Java and PHP projects *completely* separate. Keep in mind that you can serve up your Java applet in any number of ways, your PHP implementation is just one. With that knowledge in hand what you really want to do is to decide where your Applet bundle is going to live. I recommend you create a simple HTML file on your server and test loading the applet from whatever location you decide on. Then in your PHP file just write code to spit out the exact same HTML to the client.

Answer (score 0):

put the PHP files into Java project ... **wrong way**!

Try using another tool to edit your PHP scripts. Setup XAMPP server for development environment.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out when the functionality wasn't all there. I need the PHP files to access the applet though